# Storing parent-child with n amount of depth

Tags: mysql

I am recording information in a MySQL database about the components web page. For example, page A has 2 tabs, each of which has 5 links inside it. Some of those links may actually expand to be a group of 3 additional links.

Example:

```
-> Page A
-> -> Tab 1
-> -> -> Link 1
-> -> -> Link 2
-> -> -> Link 3 (Clicking this expand a section with 2 sub-links)
-> -> -> -> Link 4
-> -> -> -> Link 5

-> -> Tab 2
-> -> -> Link 6
-> -> -> Link 7
```

I am unable to figure out the best possible architecture to store this information. For example, How would I store the relationship between Page A and Link 5? I only see two options:

A.) Create 4 tables all linked with each other by an ID. This is not a valid option because the depth level (number of components between the page and the final link) will change based on which page I am on.

B.) Create 1 table that has an ID, Parent ID and item name inside it:

```
ID | Parent ID | Name
1  | -1        | Page A
2  | 1         | Tab 1
3  | 2         | Link 3
4  | 3         | Link 4
5  | 3         | Link 5
```

However, I am not sure if this is the best way to store this. For example, I will have to make as many SELECT calls as there are items to get all the children and sub-children of a given component.

Is there a better way to store this type of data?

Comment: Upgrade to MySQL 8.0, which has "Recursive CTEs" to make traversing a hierarchical tree easier.  (Also available in MariaDB 10.2.)

Comment: Read this about Managing Hierarchical Data  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/ it isn't that hard to implement the querys can get very tricky soemtimes.